# pandanic way to express desired operations in an df.groupby().agg()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question may not related to pandas, but how python handles when a function is passed as an argument in another function, I am not sure.

Anyways, Please observe the intention of the following code, the question is the triple quote:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

"""given:"""
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [100]*2+[200]*2,
        'b': np.arange(11,55,11),
    }
)
gb = df.groupby('a', as_index=0)

"""what's the pandanic way of writing the following working code:"""
gb.agg( {'b': lambda sr: sr.iat[0]})

def foo(sr, arg):
    return sr.sum() + arg
gb.agg( {'b': lambda sr: foo(sr, 888)} )

"""into the following pseudo, but not working, code:"""
gb.agg( {'b': iat[0]} )
gb.agg( {'b': foo( ,888)} )
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, since there's a `sum()` operation aside from the 1st row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `nth`

```
gb.nth(0)
Out[503]: 
     a   b
0  100  11
2  200  33
```